# How to test with jest the height of a custom statusbar?

Tags: react-native, unit-testing, jestjs

This is my component

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  View,
  Platform,
  StatusBar,
  StatusBarStyle,
  ColorValue,
} from 'react-native';
import { getStatusBarHeight } from 'react-native-iphone-x-helper';

type CustomStatusBarProps = {
  barStyle: StatusBarStyle;
  backgroundColor: ColorValue;
};

export function CustomStatusBar({
  barStyle,
  backgroundColor,
}: CustomStatusBarProps) {
  const STATUS_BAR_HEIGHT =
    Platform.OS === 'ios' ? getStatusBarHeight() + 20 : 0;
  console.log('✅ ~  STATUS_BAR_HEIGHT', STATUS_BAR_HEIGHT);

  return (
    <View
      testID="custom-status-bar"
      className={`w-full bg-${String(
        backgroundColor,
      )} h-[${STATUS_BAR_HEIGHT}]`}
    >
      <StatusBar
        translucent
        barStyle={barStyle}
        backgroundColor={backgroundColor}
      />
    </View>
  );
}
```

This is the results of the runing tests:

`jest --verbose

watchman warning:  Recrawled this watch 11 times, most recently because:
MustScanSubDirs UserDroppedTo resolve, please review the information on
https://facebook.github.io/watchman/docs/troubleshooting.html#recrawl
To clear this warning, run:
`watchman watch-del '/Users/rodrigodiasdefigueiredo/Desktop/zerelparksharing' ; watchman watch-project '/Users/rodrigodiasdefigueiredo/Desktop/zerelparksharing'`

PASS  src/components/CustomButton/**tests**/CustomButton.test.tsx
CustomButton
✓ should render the component (202 ms)
✓ should render the title (2 ms)
✓ should call onpress (2 ms)

PASS  src/components/CustomFooter/**tests**/CustomFooter.test.tsx
CustomFooter
✓ the component rendered (218 ms)
✓ the component rendered (3 ms)

console.log
✅ ~  STATUS_BAR_HEIGHT 40

```
  at log (src/components/CustomStatusBar/index.tsx:22:11)
```

console.log
✅ ~  STATUS_BAR_HEIGHT 0

```
  at log (src/components/CustomStatusBar/index.tsx:22:11)
```

console.log
✅ ~  STATUS_BAR_HEIGHT 0

```
  at log (src/components/CustomStatusBar/index.tsx:22:11)
```

FAIL  src/components/CustomStatusBar/**tests**/CustomStatusBar.test.tsx
CustomStatusBar
✓ should render the component (104 ms)
✓ should the platform be ios (2 ms)
✓ should the platform be android
✕ should render the component with the height 40 for IOS (3 ms)
✕ should render the component with the height 0 for Android (2 ms)

● CustomStatusBar › should render the component with the height 40 for IOS

```
expect(received).toBe(expected) // Object.is equality

Expected: 40
Received: undefined

  39 |     );
  40 |     const customStatusBar = getByTestId('custom-status-bar');
> 41 |     expect(customStatusBar.props.style[0].height).toBe(40);
     |                                                   ^
  42 |   });
  43 |
  44 |   it('should render the component with the height 0 for Android', () => {

  at Object.toBe (src/components/CustomStatusBar/__tests__/CustomStatusBar.test.tsx:41:51)
```

● CustomStatusBar › should render the component with the height 0 for Android

```
expect(received).toBe(expected) // Object.is equality

Expected: 0
Received: undefined

  50 |     );
  51 |     const customStatusBar = getByTestId('custom-status-bar');
> 52 |     expect(customStatusBar.props.style[0].height).toBe(0);
     |                                                   ^
  53 |   });
  54 | });
  55 |

  at Object.toBe (src/components/CustomStatusBar/__tests__/CustomStatusBar.test.tsx:52:51)
```

----------------------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------

| File | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| All files | 7.03 | 4.34 | 8.88 | 7.14 |  |
| components/CustomButton | 100 | 100 | 100 | 100 |  |
| index.tsx | 100 | 100 | 100 | 100 |  |
| components/CustomFooter | 100 | 100 | 100 | 100 |  |
| index.tsx | 100 | 100 | 100 | 100 |  |
| components/CustomStatusBar | 100 | 100 | 100 | 100 |  |
| index.tsx | 100 | 100 | 100 | 100 |  |
| components/CustomToast | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |  |
| index.tsx | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 12-64 |
| components/OpenDoorModal | 0 | 100 | 0 | 0 |  |
| index.tsx | 0 | 100 | 0 | 0 | 17-62 |
| screens/Home | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |  |
| index.tsx | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 11-91 |
| screens/Login | 0 | 100 | 0 | 0 |  |
| index.tsx | 0 | 100 | 0 | 0 | 9-13 |
| screens/Menu | 0 | 100 | 0 | 0 |  |
| index.tsx | 0 | 100 | 0 | 0 | 4-5 |
| screens/MyAccess | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |  |
| index.tsx | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 5-16 |
| screens/OnBoarding | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |  |
| index.tsx | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 24-180 |
| slides.ts | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |  |
| screens/Vehicles | 0 | 100 | 0 | 0 |  |
| index.tsx | 0 | 100 | 0 | 0 | 4-5 |
| screens/Wallet | 0 | 100 | 0 | 0 |  |
| index.tsx | 0 | 100 | 0 | 0 | 4-5 |
| slices/counter | 0 | 100 | 0 | 0 |  |
| counterSlice.ts | 0 | 100 | 0 | 0 | 9-34 |
| ---------------------------- | --------- | ---------- | --------- | --------- | ------------------- |
| Test Suites: 1 failed, 2 passed, 3 total |  |  |  |  |  |
| Tests: 2 failed, 8 passed, 10 total |  |  |  |  |  |
| Snapshots: 0 total |  |  |  |  |  |
| Time: 2.343 s |  |  |  |  |  |
| Ran all test suites.` |  |  |  |  |  |

I'm trying to test the height of the statusbar on both platforms IOS and Android to get 100 on test coverage.`

Answer (score 0):

you need to mock your `platform` & `getStatusBarHeight` before expect 40.

```
Platform.OS = 'ios'

jest.mock('react-native-iphone-x-helper', () => {
  return {
    getStatusBarHeight: jest.fn().mockReturnValue(20)
  }
})

expect(STYLE).toBe(40)
```

Comment: `Cannot find module 'Platform' from 'src/components/CustomStatusBar/__tests__/CustomStatusBar.test.tsx'`

Comment: `import { Platform } from 'react-native'`

`Platform.OS = 'ios'`

instead of jest.mock('Platform ......